# Specflow Integration test with HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, specflow

I'm trying to create some specflow tests and using a WebApplicationFactory and want to moq HttpClient calls with Moq.Contrib.HttpClient.
So when i call my client, it's not intiated well (doesn't match with the moq)

Any ideas?
Thanks

So i've 2 differents HttpClients

```
var httpMessageHandler1 = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
            httpMessageHandler1.SetupRequest(HttpMethod.Post, $"http://localhost/api/Method1");
            var httpMessageHandler2 = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
            httpMessageHandler2
                .SetupRequest(HttpMethod.Post, $"http://localhost/api/Method2")
                .ReturnsResponse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response), "application/json");
```

I inject them like this in the stepDefinition class :

```
var application = new WebFactory<Program>()
                .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                        services.AddMediatR(typeof(DeviceRequestModel));
                        services.AddHttpClient("Client1").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => httpMessageHandler1.Object);
                        services.AddHttpClient("Client2").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => httpMessageHandler2.Object);
                    });
                });
```

Here is my WebFactory :

```
 internal class WebFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
            builder.UseEnvironment(Environments.Development);
            builder.UseTestServer()
                   .ConfigureTestServices(
                        services =>
                        {
                            services.AddScoped<TStartup>();

                            // Remove existing IHttpClientFactory and HttpClient
                            var httpClientFactoryDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IHttpClientFactory));
                            services.Remove(httpClientFactoryDescriptor);

                            var httpClientDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient));
                            services.Remove(httpClientDescriptor);
                        });
        }
    }
```

In my Command, i get the IHttpClientFactory

```
        public Handler(IHttpClientFactory factory)
        {
            this.client = factory.CreateClient("Client1");
        }
```

So when i do the

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await this.client.PostAsync
```

I've got this exception 'System.InvalidOperationException' dans System.Net.Http.dll and my client is not intiated well (doesn't match with the moq)

[image: Here's what i get on debug]

So it's not my moq object from services.AddHttpClient("Client1").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => httpMessageHandler1.Object);

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't match with the moq" mean?

Comment: My client created from the factory doesn't match with this ones services.AddHttpClient("Client1").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => httpMessageHandler1.Object);
So it's an "empty" HttpClient

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is. Please include the full exception message and stacktrace.

Comment: I add an image of what i get on debut on description's link "Here's what i get on debug"

Comment: Ok, interesting. It appears you are getting the real HttpClient object instead?

Comment: Looks like `factory.CreateClient("...")` needs to be mocked.

Comment: I think, i'm ok with moq.contrib.HttpClient doc https://github.com/maxkagamine/Moq.Contrib.HttpClient#integration-tests